# Microsoft Teams Incoming Webhook is not working with BambooHR Webhook

Tags: rest, microsoft-teams, webhooks, office365connectors

I configured an incoming webhook for my Teams channel and also configured BambooHR webhook with Teams incoming webhook URL to post data to the channel. Even posting data from different places is working well, it is not working for BambooHR webhook. Why this problem occurs and how can I fix this?

Comment: can you please check what BambooHR is trying to push and in which format. Please refer this (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/connectors/connectors)  for more information on incoming Webhook.

Comment: I configured BambooHR format as JSON and it is working on another IP address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft Teams Incoming Webhook accepts only one format and it is below. Whatever you need should be the value of the text.

```
{ text:"" }
```

None of the other formats is valid for it, that's why BambooHR Webhook did not work. I wish they had a proper JSON format.